# os.access returns True, but file is not writable

Tags: python, file-permissions

I have this code:

```py
import os

print(os.access("tst.txt", os.R_OK))
open("tst.txt", "rb")

# File Permissions:
# Owner: Trusted Installer
# Administrators and my user: deny all permissions
```

`os.access` returns `True` but opening the file raises a PermissionError exception.

And if I try this on another file (like cmd.exe, notepad.exe, System32 dir itself, or ANY other file) it always returns True.

If a file is non-existent it return False.

SO: `True` on any existing file. Even if there is no write access.

I couldn't find anything about this on the Internet.

Does anybody know why this issue occurs?

EDIT:
Of course my script is not running as Administrator.

No matter if I test read or write access.

Comment: Per the [documentation for `os.access`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.access): "Note: I/O operations may fail even when access() indicates that they would succeed, particularly for operations on network filesystems which may have permissions semantics beyond the usual POSIX permission-bit model."

Comment: You are checking for write access but opening for read access. Is that correct?

Comment: no, im not able to read and to write, i have no permission, but os.access returns True,

Comment: no matter if I test read or write access

Comment: Yeah, I read the docs. This is not a network file, and it returns True for any file on my computer, I tested it recursively.

Comment: I dont think its a problem with my script, more like a problem with my computer but i dont know why

Comment: Is `os.access` *supposed* to work under Windows? The documentation refers to a Unix system call for more information.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `os.access` does not check user permissions on Windows, it only checks for the readonly flag being set or not.

> Note that os.access doesn't check file security on Windows. W_OK just checks the read-only flag. Thus using try...except is really the only possibility if you're on Windows and aren't using the Windows security API .

from http://net-informations.com/python/file/exists.htm

In this case, you may have to wrap a try...except around your code

Comment: Thank You, thats what i searched for

Comment: I learned something new too. I've always used the whole easier to ask for forgiveness model in python